# Office 2013 sheet.copy does nothing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have the following code correctly running in Office 2010 but not in Office 2013. No errors executing it in Excel 2010 and no errors executing it in Excel 2013, but in Excel 2013 it does nothing.

```
Dim strDocument As Variant
strDocument = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft All Excel Files,*.xls*,All Files,*.*", 1, "Open File", , False)
If strDocument = False Then
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Exit Sub
End If
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strDocument

ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

Sheets(Array("Mobile", "Fisso")).Select
Sheets("Fisso").Activate
Sheets(Array("Mobile", "Fisso")).Copy Before:=Workbooks(toolName).Sheets(1)
Sheets("Mobile (2)").Select
Sheets("Mobile (2)").name = "Mobile AS IS"
Call CreatePrimaryKey("Mobile AS IS")
Range("A1").Select
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
```

The problem in Office 2013 is that it does not copy anything, no errors. I would expect it to copy 2 sheets (Fisso and Mobile) from the active workbook to my "toolName" workbook.

Are there any known issues regarding this?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Where is `toolName` variable dimensioned, is it pointing to the correct workbook or is that the active workbook?

Comment: Do you have an `On Error` statement before this snippet? If yes, are you sure the duplicate sheet in Excel 2013 is named `Name (2)` rather than `Name(2)` (without space)? If not, please tell us on which line you get the error. But in any case, if there's this On Error statement please comment it for the moment and tell us the error, it is not known any compatibility problem on this side.

Comment: Where is `toolName` declared and assigned? The closest thing I can see is `strDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

Understood. office 2013 cannot minimize a workbook and maintain excel window up at the same time. This is possible in office 2010 only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2013 and this code worked fine for me. It Copies the sheet, then moves it to another workbook.

```
Sub CopySheet()
Sheets("Test").Select
Sheets("Test").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(1)
End Sub
```